# How to retrieve corresponding value of a column?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one named `logs` the other named `location`.

In `logs`, I have the following:

```
___________________________
| id | message | location |
'-------------------------'
| 1  | test    | 1        |
| 2  | test    | 2        |
| 3  | test    | 1        |
| 4  | test    | 1        |
___________________________
```

In the `location` table, I have this:

```
_________________
| id | location |
'---------------'
| 1  | US       |
| 2  | UK       |
_________________
```

What I want to ooutput with my query is this:

```
___________________________
| id | message | location |
'-------------------------'
| 1  | test    | US       |
| 2  | test    | UK       |
| 3  | test    | US       |
| 4  | test    | US       |
___________________________
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `INNER JOIN` to get your desired result... For reference http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: what you have tried and where you got problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select lg.id, lg.message, lo.location 
from logs lg, location lo 
where lg.location = lo.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT logs.id, logs.message,location.location 
from logs, location 
where logs.location= location.location
```

Join applied in this query is Inner Join.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select a.id,a.message,b.location 
 from 
 logs a , location b 
 where 
 logs.location = location.id;
```

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
SELECT a.id, a.message, b.location 
      FROM logs a 
           LEFT JOIN location b 
           ON a.location = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT lo.id,message,location
 FROM logs lo ,location l
 WHERE lo.location = l.id
```